# what are the locations to store symmetric keys on the embedded controller without HSM or certs involvement?

Tags: hsm, embedded-system

I am trying to find the locations on the embedded devices with micros that don't support HSM/SHE. What are the ideas/suggestions for storing the symmetric keys? I found solutions that suggest using public/private keys to encrypt this symmetric key but the micros are not capable of doing this.

Comment: An Arduino is capable of public key encryption. Even a small Attiny85 have enough memory to do so.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.